# Python: time.sleep functions unexpectedly?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple function that will type out a string letter by letter, such as in a game, where text scrolls.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import time

def ScrollingText(s):
     s=str(s)
     for letter in s:
          print(letter, end="")
          time.sleep(.05)
     print("")    # newline at the end
if __name__=='__main__':
     ScrollingText("Hello World!")
```

However when I run, it waits, then dumps out the whole string at once. I'm new to python (and this forum as well) so if anyone can point me in the right direction and show me what I'm missing here in time.sleep I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Offtopic: You're not forced to finish each line by `;` in Python. It's more pythonic to remove them.

Comment: Let me say this more clear: It's bullshit to end the lines with a `;`.

Comment: @ Maxime, Matthias I learned Java first so that's where that habit comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not have a newline in your string, python will buffer it. You have to explicitly flush the output after each character like this:

```
import sys
import time

def ScrollingText(s):
     s=str(s)
     for letter in s:
          print(letter, end="")
          sys.stdout.flush()
          time.sleep(.05)
     print("")     # newline at the end
```

For better performance, I/O is usually buffered, that is, python will collect the data you print until it can send it out as a large block (this also goes for file I/O by the way). By calling [flush()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) on sys.stdout (which is the file object where print writes to by default), you force python to send your data to the operating system (and that will send it to your terminal).

Comment: print usually does not need flush. 50 msec delay is too small

Comment: @volcano: [Manual says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) that the output buffering is determined by the file (which is sys.stdout here). I would not know of any file implementation in python which buffers based on timeouts.

Comment: you are write. Print behaves differently when strings is not terminated by \n